# React-Native Face detect from list of images

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

i want to detect faces from list of images which are listed from photo albums..

here is my code..

```
  // get All images from particular album

    await CameraRoll.getPhotos({
          first: count,
          after,
          assetType: 'Photos',
          groupTypes: 'All',
          groupName: this.props.navigation.state.params.album,
        })
          .then(r => {
            this.setState({ data: r.edges, isLoading: false, });

            this.state.data.map((p, index) => {
              this.getFaces(p.node.image.uri);
            });
          })
}
```

// Detect faces from list of images

```
async getFaces(uri) {
    await FaceDetector.detectFacesAsync(uri).then(res => {
      if (res.faces.length > 0) {
        console.log('Has faces: ' + uri);
        this.state.faceImage.push(uri);  // array of face images and set it to Flatlist
      } else {
        console.log('No faces: ' + uri);
      }
    });

      this.setState({
        faceImage: this.state.faceImage,
        isLoading: false,
      });

  }
```

All things are worked correctly but when image array size was big then my app was stuck and close only in android device.

Answer (score 0):

Try to split it to new array when the size of the array is to big

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to save it to file and load it from there?